# Efficient way to round n/4 upward

Tags: c, algorithm, math, optimization, rounding

I have an integer number n and I need to rounds n/4 upward. For performance reason I need to find out a fast way in C. The division by 4 can be done using a >> 2 shift operation but I don't know about the round. I could use ceil but I am worried about performance.

Comment: Before worrying about performance, *measure!* See if what you think is a bottleneck actually is. Don't do manual optimizations before you know if it's really needed (manually optimized code is often hard to read, understand and maintain).

Comment: The general formula for divide-and-ceiling is `#define DIV_CEIL(n,d) (((n)-1)/(d)+1)`.

Comment: @barakmanos: Wouldn't that break for `unsigned` where `n==0`?

Comment: @TimČas it's broken for all negative numbers, as division (from C99 onwards) truncates towards zero.

Comment: @abligh: Quite possibly (depending on what one means by "upward"). I didn't bother analyzing it that much, I've just spotted (and pointed out) the obvious. Point is, it's broken for at least one important case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your operand is non-negative, how about:

```
unsigned int
roundupdiv4 (unsigned int n)
{
    return (n+3)>>2;
}
```

Note that any sensible compiler will compile `/4` of an `unsigned int` as `>>2` anyway.

I can confirm that by compiling the above with `gcc -O3 -S`:

```
    .file   "x.c"
    .text
    .p2align 4,,15
    .globl  roundupdiv4
    .type   roundupdiv4, @function
roundupdiv4:
.LFB0:
    .cfi_startproc
    leal    3(%rdi), %eax
    shrl    $2, %eax
    ret
    .cfi_endproc
.LFE0:
    .size   roundupdiv4, .-roundupdiv4
    .ident  "GCC: (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2"
    .section    .note.GNU-stack,"",@progbits
```

and noting the output is *exactly the same* if I substitute `>>2` by `/4`.

Also note that I've used `unsigned int` as `>>` is implementation defined for negative signed left operands (i.e. shifting negative values right). If you want a working one that rounds up (strictly up) for signed values:

```
int
roundupdiv4 (int n)
{
    return ((n>0)?(n+3):n)/4;
}
```

because integer division uses truncation rounding, i.e. rounds up for negative numbers (towards zero) anyway. (That's for [C99 onwards](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c/3602857#3602857); it's implementation defined in C89).

If by round up you meant 'round away from zero' then:

```
int
roundawayfromzerodiv4 (int n)
{
    return ((n>0)?(n+3):(n-3))/4;
}
```

Comment: Minor correction: `>>` is implementation-defined for negative left operands (and usually sign-extends); `<<` is undefined (even `(0,-1) << 0` is).

Comment: @mafso: thanks - I think I've fixed that w.r.t. `>>`. `<<` is not used here but for my interest, ISO/IEC 9899:2011 s6.5.7 §4 says *"The result of E1 << E2 is E1 left-shifted E2 bit positions; vacated bits are filled with zeros ... [text if E1 is unsigned] ... If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1 × 2E2 is representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value; otherwise, the behavior is undefined."* - implies to me you can safely left-shift 0!

Comment: I'd be rather surprised if `/4` were converted to `>>2` by any mainstream compiler, at least for `int`: they're different for negative operands.  C99 requires /4 to truncate the fractional part (so `(-1) / 4` should be `0`), while (as already noted), the behaviour of `>>` for negative operands is implementation defined, but I'd expect most implementations to define `>>2` so that it shifts the bits (either sign-extending or not).  With or without sign-extension, `(-1) >> 2` is not going to give `0`.

Comment: @MarkDickinson - re conversion, arrgh, I meant `>>2` of an `unsigned int` - fixed. Re `(-1)>>2 != 0` let's hope so, but in theory a C compiler could legally do this.

Comment: @MarkDickinson - Then be surprised.  See disassembled functions in my answer.

Comment: @BrianMcFarland: Ah, nice.  Thank you.  Just tried this for myself, under Clang with -O3, and a simple `/4` on (signed) int turns into a combination of two arithmetic shifts, one bit shift, and an addition.

Comment: @MarkDickinson be more surprised - I've just done it and it turns out with exactly the same code for `unsigned int`s. (`gcc-4.8.real (Ubuntu 4.8.2-19ubuntu1) 4.8.2`)

Comment: @MarkDickinson -  Weird. I thought Clang was general on par with or better than gcc for performance?   FYIY, it was gcc 4.8.2 from the ubuntu repo, so not exactly bleeding edge.

Comment: @abligh: wrt left-shifting by 0 [edit: left-shifting _negative_ values by 0]: I read that as _(If `E1` has a signed type **and** nonnegative value [...]); otherwise, the behavior is undefined._ -- so I think, it's UB. (I've read this somewhere here on SO, don't remember where, but I think, this interpretation is correct.)

Comment: @mafso, but 0 *is* non-negative and (by assumption) a signed type.

Comment: @abligh, `E1` is the left operand, not the right one, `0 << 0` is defined, of course.

Comment: @mafso yes indeed. There is no prohibition on E2 being zero, or on E2 at all, save that E1 x 2^E2 is representable in the result type, which it clearly always will be when left-shifting by zero bits. Am I missing something?

Comment: @abligh No, I don't think you miss anything, `E2` can always be 0 (if I don't miss anything). And I'm not sure if we're talking about the same thing :) My point was just that even `(0,-1) << 0` is UB (where the left operand is negative, not the right one).

Comment: @mafso ah apologies, it's notation confusion. I thought by `(0,-1)<<0` you meant `0<<0` *and* `-1<<0`.

Comment: @abligh: Sorry, I should've commented on that... I just used the comma operator to not make it a constant expression and avoid the (even more off-topic) discussion if an implementation may refuse to compile (and must diagnose it), because a constraint on constants is violated (Is "undefined behavior" _in the range of representable values for its type_?).

Comment: @mafso yes, eventually it dawned on me, having considered how that couldn't be an interval either :-)

Answer (score 3):

This optimizes into 7 instructions including the return on my x86_64 machine with `gcc -O3`.

```
int div4roundup(int x)
{
   return (x & 3) ? (x >> 2) + 1 : (x>>2);
}
```

disassembly:

```
int div4roundup(int x)
{
  return (x & 3) ? (x >> 2) + 1 : (x>>2);
   0:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
   2:   31 d2                   xor    %edx,%edx
   4:   c1 f8 02                sar    $0x2,%eax
   7:   83 e7 03                and    $0x3,%edi
   a:   0f 95 c2                setne  %dl
   d:   01 d0                   add    %edx,%eax
}
   f:   c3                      retq
```

Compared with abligh's equivalent solution:

```
int
roundupdiv4 (int n)
{
    return ((n>0)?(n+3):n)/4;
   0:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   2:   8d 47 03                lea    0x3(%rdi),%eax
   5:   7f 05                   jg     c <fc+0xc>
   7:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   9:   0f 49 c7                cmovns %edi,%eax
   c:   c1 f8 02                sar    $0x2,%eax
}
   f:   c3                      retq
```

Compared with abligh's alternate solution:

```
0000000000000000 <roundawayfromzerodiv4>:
int
roundawayfromzerodiv4 (int n)
{
    return ((n>0)?(n+3):(n-3))/4;
   0:   85 ff                   test   %edi,%edi
   2:   7e 0c                   jle    10 <roundawayfromzerodiv4+0x10>
   4:   8d 47 03                lea    0x3(%rdi),%eax
   7:   c1 f8 02                sar    $0x2,%eax
   a:   c3                      retq   
   b:   0f 1f 44 00 00          nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
  10:   89 f8                   mov    %edi,%eax
  12:   83 e8 03                sub    $0x3,%eax
  15:   0f 48 c7                cmovs  %edi,%eax
  18:   c1 f8 02                sar    $0x2,%eax
}
  1b:   c3                      retq
```

**EDIT:**  Thought I came up with something faster than the other answer then realized I was comparing two slightly different computations.  Our two "rounds strictly up" functions are equal in instruction count, but slightly different.  Haven't analyzed disassembly enough to know which is faster.